# JFreeChart - insert photos at specific locations on chart

Tags: jfreechart, photo

I want to make a chart reflecting signal changing during a movie timeline. Any suggestions that I can insert multiple photos (images) at specific location on a JFreeChart? I want to create preview photos of different chapters of the movie on the time series and plot the changing signal chart above that time series. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [XYImageAnnotation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYImageAnnotation.html) (assuming that your chart is created using an `XYPlot`).

Comment: works as charm! Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much, David Gilbert